# Read validation message from external library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a Global Resource file for Error messages and I am attaching the associated message to the validator control as following.

```
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVTest" 
                        CssClass="ErrorMessage" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:ErrorMessage, RequiredFieldTestKey %>" 
                        ControlToValidate="ReqFldTestTextbox"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

This is working fine.

Now I am planning to move all the Global Resources to a different library let say `MyResourceLibrary` and created a resource file with name `ErrorMessage`. I have added the reference of the library to my ASP.NET project and trying to acces the message from my library as follwong.

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVTest" 
                        CssClass="ErrorMessage" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources: MyResourceLibrary.ErrorMessage, RequiredFieldTestKey %>" 
                        ControlToValidate="ReqFldTestTextbox"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did this using server side code like follwong.

```
RVTest.ErrorMessage =MyLibrary.ValidationMessages.RequiredField;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your resource file is named the same as the page you are on (i.e. Default.aspx.resx)

You can add meta:resourcekey as so:

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVTest" 
                    CssClass="ErrorMessage" runat="server" 
                    meta:resourcekey="RequiredFieldTestKey" 
                    ControlToValidate="ReqFldTestTextbox"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: We can’t have the resource file with the same name as aspx file as we are making a single resource file for error messages and that is in a different library.

Comment: Then you can set it in code on Page_Load

RVTest.ErrorMessage = Resources.ErrorMessages.RequiredFieldTestKey;

Comment: +1 Thanks.

I already did that and it was working, I am trying to avoid the extra efforts of managing this at server side.